# Positioning radiobuttons and Labels vertically in pure css

Tags: html, css

The following HTML is generated from a library and cannot be changed in any way, so I need a CSS only solution for my problem. I would like for the radio buttons to appear vertically instead of left to right to each other like so [image]

This is my code.

```
<span class="buttonset" id="test">

      <input type="radio" id="test_1" name="test" value="CC">
      <label for="test_1">Option 1</label>

      <input type="radio" id="test_2" name="test" value="PL">
      <label for="test_2">Option 2</label>

      <input type="radio" id="test_3" name="test" value="AL">
      <label for="test_3">Option 3</label>

      <input type="radio" id="test_4" name="test" value="HL">
      <label for="test_4">Option 4</label>

      <input type="radio" id="test_5" name="test" value="CL">
      <label for="test_5">Option 5</label>

      <input type="radio" id="test_6" name="test" value="CL">
      <label for="test_6">Option 6</label>

  </span>
```

See also http://jsfiddle.net/QHvhs/
Is there a pure CSS way to get a new line after each input and label element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use css3 pseudo selector `:after` to insert a line break after every label, making the list vertical.

```
.buttonset label:after {
    content:"\A"; 
    white-space:pre;
}
```

live demo: <kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/QHvhs/2/)**</kbd>

Comment: Ooh, you dirty little cheater :p +1 for the CSS-only answer and beating me to it.

Answer (score 0):

This is more semantically better.

You shouldn't have the form elements inside of a SPAN, but rather use DIV.

```
<span class="buttonset" id="test">
```

to

```
<div class="buttonset" id="test">
```

And the way you should wrap LABEL is

```
<label for="test_6"><input type="radio" id="test_6" name="test" value="CL"> Option 6</label>
```

You can then use CSS selector in a better semantic way

```
.buttonset label {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Yes I agree, that would be nice. But I cannot change the HTML in any way. I seemed to have been too vague about that part. Will edit the text accordingly.